# Fix dot issue on TextField in Titanium

Tags: titanium

I am working on titanium application.When I have written text and press space button twice then dot is showing on Textfield and TextArea.Please suggest me how to fix it.I have attached the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature on your phone, has nothing to do with Titanium. Go to `Settings -> General -> Keyboard` and turn off `"." Shortcut`